# Ignore crossref

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I have few bibliography items in a bib file with `crossref`. I want the bibliography engine to stop looking for it.

Say, I have the MWE (copied from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401142/38244)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mincrossrefs=99]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{duck2015,
    author = {Duck, D.},
    title = {Duck tales},
    crossref = {ICRC2015},
}

@inproceedings{mouse2015,
    author = {Mouse, M.},
    title = {Mouse stories},
    crossref = {ICRC2015},
}

@proceedings{ICRC2015,
    title = "{Proceedings of the 34\textsuperscript{th} International Cosmic Ray Conference}",
    year = "2015",
    month = aug,
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{duck2015}
\cite{mouse2015}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I want that it will simply ignore the `crossref`, as if it was not present. How can I do that?

Comment: Can't you simply delete the parent entry?

Comment: @samcarter There are too many of them. Not possible to do manually.

Comment: Can you do a global search-and-replace of `crossref` for (say) `xcrossref` in the bib file? If you feel a bit squeamish about making a global change of this type, simply save the modified bib file under a different name; that way, you can say to yourself that you didn't vandalize the original bib file...

Comment: `sed '^[^a-zA-Z]*crossref[^a-zA-Z]*=/d' <name of bib file> > <name of new bib file>`? Can you say why you want to ignore the `crossref` exactly?

Answer (score 3):

You can reset the inheritance rule:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mincrossrefs=99]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{duck2015,
    author = {Duck, D.},
    title = {Duck tales},
    crossref = {ICRC2015},
}

@inproceedings{mouse2015,
    author = {Mouse, M.},
    title = {Mouse stories},
    crossref = {ICRC2015},
}

@proceedings{ICRC2015,
    title = "{Proceedings of the 34\textsuperscript{th} International Cosmic Ray Conference}",
    year = "2015",
    month = aug,
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefaultInheritance{all=false}
\ResetDataInheritance

\begin{document}
\cite{duck2015}
\cite{mouse2015}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

But as you can see in the screenshot you will perhaps have to correct the drivers if your real bib doesn't have necessary fields.