# Wasn't there a way to cite multiple chapters of a book referencing the book's entry rather than redundantly repeating information?

Tags: bibtex

I vaguely remember but can't find on line that there was some "correct" way to cite multiple chapters in the same book. First you would enter the book as a book, then you would reference that citation somehow in the "incollection" or whatever you use for the individual chapter. I also vaguely remember that I could never get this to work. Is it now deprecated? Or is it now wildly popular and I'm just searching the wrong terms?

Comment: Do you mean cross references in BibTeX? e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401142/36145

Comment: Yes, if you want to make that an answer instead of a comment, feel free & I'll say you answered. Given that I couldn't google this up, I think it's worth having another stackexchange entry about it.

Comment: The finger that points to the moon is not the moon... :-)